# Vb.net - select from datatable where integer is in list/array inside one of the columns

Tags: vb.net, select, datatable

I'm trying to retrieve rows from a datatable where an integer exists within a list/string contained within one of the datatable columns.

for context, this is the number pertaining to the day of the week.

The column in the datatable is called 'runDays', and is a string which would look like this :  1,2,3,5    (meaning monday, tuesday, wednesday and friday in my region).

This is as close as I've got so far (my actual select statement is considerably more complex, but all working perfectly aside from this 'nowDay IN' bit, so I simplified it for the purposes of seeking assistance)...

```
 Dim nowDay As Integer = CInt(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
 Dim result() As DataRow = dtbSchedule.Select(nowDay & " IN (runDays)")
```

I feel like I'm close, but not close enough - this generates an Evaluation exception...

> System.Data.EvaluateException: Only constant expressions are allowed in the expression list for the IN operator.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for the correct syntax here?

Edit:

```
 Dim result() As DataRow = dtbSchedule.Select("runType = 'weekly' AND '" & nowdate & "' >= startDate AND '" & nowdate & "' <= endDate  AND runTime = '" & nowtime & "' AND " & nowDay & " IN (runDays)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The column in the datatable is called 'runDays', and is a string

```
    Dim nowDay As String = CInt(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).ToString
    Dim result() As DataRow
    result = (From r In dtbSchedule.AsEnumerable
                 Where r("runDays").ToString.Contains(nowDay)
                 Select r).ToArray
```

EDIT:  shows some of the other conditions.  Should be able to figure out the rest.  Note that I assumed some of the data types.

```
    result = (From r In dtbSchedule.AsEnumerable
                Where r("runType").ToString = "weekly" AndAlso
                      nowDate >= CDate(r("startDate")) AndAlso
                      r("runDays").ToString.Contains(nowDay)
                 Select r).ToArray
```

Comment: ok, so i feel that I've screwed myself over by simplifying the query in my question, as I now have no idea how to include all of my other clauses in the query as you have demonstrated. I will edit my original question and include the full query... @dbasnett would you mind expanding?

Comment: @John - I added SOME of the other conditions.